# Visual Studio Automatically generate XML Documentation with XSLT

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, documentation, xmldocument

I have VS.Net set to automatically generate an XML with the XMLDoc comments in my code on build. This is done through the build properties of the project.  I also have an XSLT to style the XML.

Is there a way to have VS append the xml-stylesheet to the file upon generating?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the System.IO object. Look at StreamReader and StreamWriter in particular, but possibly also File (which has a .Append Function).

Comment: I apologize for any misunderstanding. I am not writing an application that writes xml.  When building a project in Visual Studio there is a flag that will automatically generate an XML from any XMLDoc comments in your code.

Comment: Oh, sorry...I did misunderstand.  Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to your question.